# Apply header & footer settings (Adobe Acrobat Pro)

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line-arguments, acrobat

Searching for a solution to a way to apply the settings xml file to header & footer of pdf file. I have tried the following command line, which arises no errors but I didn't get the output pdf file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /t "Input.pdf" /s "MYSETTINGS_YK.xml" /o "Output.pdf"
```

Any idea how to apply the settings to pdf file through the command line?

Answer (score 1):

In reality a PDF has no concept of margins nor their data. It is the print driver from Adobe or not, that adds the headline and footline as overwrites IF marginal space is available.

Valid Acrobat command line switches are here
https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_overview.pdf#page=52

So `/t` is **t**erminal **t**ask **t**erminate and stay resident for fast printing
and `/s` is for **s**uppress **s**plash **s**creen
there are a few others related to print such as
`/p` which invokes **p**rinter **p**ort **p**rompt where you can manually set driver headers and footers

it also includes a note

> You can use a plug-in or JavaScript to modify a PDF document by cropping and rotating pages, numbering pages, and **adding headers and footers.**

AcrobatPro has "Action script sequences" for programming (and it is so long ago cannot remember if they were command line runnable).

So if installed with "File Type Allocations" it may be possible to open a filename.sequ (similar to opening a filename.FDF) since apparently, you can also double-click a .sequ file to import an action per https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html

As an alternative way to provide headers and footers is, you can overstamp the margins using command line tools. There are many such as free open source for commercial users (subject to license) including

[qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) a powerhouse of abilities many way beyond pdftk will allow overlap page(s) with marginal notes (Apache License Version 2.0)

[pdfcpu](http://pdfcpu.io/core/stamp) very good toolkit including a multi-stamp similar to pdftk but also text and image overlays (Apache License Version 2.0)

Comment: So there is no direct way to add headers and footers or even apply xml file that contains settings to the header & footer?
I have spent two days searching but with no use!!